# Why is an override on navigationController:willShowViewController:animated necessary for tab bars

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application that creates a tabbarcontroller from the AppDelegate. I wanted to have a button added to the nav bar but was unable to. Eventually I managed to get hold of some working code, but I don't really understand it.

The steps were:

1. Confirm the AppDelegate to UINavigationControllerDelegate
2. Set the  rootNavigationController.delegate = self
3. Override navigationController:willShowViewController:animated and tabBarController:didSelectViewController

I think I follow the **tabBarController:didSelectViewController** code, but am lost in what is happening with **navigationController:willShowViewController:animated**.

```
- (void) tabBarController: (UITabBarController*) tabBarController didSelectViewController: (UIViewController*) viewController
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
     self.tabBarController.navigationItem.title = viewController.navigationItem.title;
     self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems;
     self.tabBarController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems;
     }
  }



- (void) navigationController: (UINavigationController*) navigationController
   willShowViewController: (UIViewController*) viewController
                 animated: (BOOL) animated
    {
      if (viewController == tabBarController)
      {
        UIViewController* tabViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    SEL willShowSel = @selector(navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:);

      if ([tabViewController respondsToSelector: willShowSel])
      {
        UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate>* vc =
            (UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate>*) tabViewController;
        [vc navigationController: navigationController willShowViewController: vc animated: animated];
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is likely dealing with problems that occur using a `UITabBarController` within a `UINavigationController`. The `UITabBarController` documentation states that it needs to be the root view controller (i.e. NOT within a `UINavigationController`) and using it in other ways can cause problems.

What the code appears to be doing is capturing the event normally passed to `viewController`, checking if it is a `UITabBarController` and if it is, then it checks whether the visible view in the `UITabBarController` responds to this method, and if it does then it passes the method (selector) call on to that view.

If it is possible, I'd recommend pulling the `UITabBarController` out from being embedded in the `UINavigationController`. Might take a bit of work, but will make your code compliant. (And remove need for `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I would have thought it was a fairly standard design - tab bars are the top level and a nav bar with a button.

Comment: I think it's simpler than that: The intent appears to be to add the button to the TBC's nav bar but TBCs do not have nav bars; only the child controllers do.